# How to run hook_update for the database

Tags: database, updating

Suppose we have a simple module with 3 files: test.info, test. install and test.module.

#### test.install

```
<?php
function test_schema() {

    $schema['test'] = array(
        //fields
        'fields' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true
                ),
            ),
        //additional properties
        'primary key' => array('id'),
        );

    return $schema;
}
```

When I install the module via the web interface, the table is created. Then I add hook_update:

```
function test_update_7100() {
    $spec = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'description' => "New Col",
        'length' => 20,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        );
    db_add_field( 'test', 'name', $spec);
}
```

Now I need to run the update function to modify the table. But I don't know where I can do it. Module is not present in "Modules" -> "Update".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run just `drush updb -y` on your site folder.

Comment: Yes, how to do without drush?

Comment: why you want to do it without drush?

Comment: go here admin/modules/update and press the check manually button..

Comment: Currently, it gives an error on my Windows XP machine: cannot find the path specified. Will try to fix.

Comment: No, unfortunately check manually didn't give me an option to update the module

Comment: is your module enabled and in whitch file you wrote your hook_update?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I wrote it to test.install

Comment: what is going on? :/

Comment: Actually, I was able to run it through drush - the database is updated. But I am still interested, why it was not listed in the list of updates?